# chart and pdf generation using canvasjs and jspdf

Tags: pdf-generation, jspdf, canvasjs

using canvasjs and jspdf to generate chart and export as pdf. Chart is getting generated but export as pdf is not working.what I am missing here,if someone can suggest.your time will be appreciated.Thanks

.

```
<head>

<title>Graphical Representation Of Stores</title>
<style type="/css">
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form>

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
<button id="exportButton" type="button">Export as PDF</button>

<script type="text/javascript">


var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
{
        title: {
            text: "Exporting chart using jsPDF & toDataurl"
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "spline",
            dataPoints: [ 
                { x: 10, y: 4 }, 
                { x: 20, y: 7 },
                { x: 30, y: 2 },
                { x: 40, y: 3 },
                { x: 50, y: 5 }
            ]
        }
        ]
});
chart.render();

var canvas = $("#chartContainer.canvasjs-chart-canvas").get(0);
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
//console.log(dataURL);

$("#exportButton").click(function(){
    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.addImage(dataURL, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
    pdf.save("download.pdf");
});
</script>
</form>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Post the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 4):

Manish,

The issue is with the selector `var canvas = $("#chartContainer.canvasjs-chart-canvas").get(0);` which should ideally be `var canvas = $("#chartContainer .canvasjs-chart-canvas").get(0);` (space needed). And it works pretty fine after that.

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/cm1qyk2L/).